# Azure Security Center freshness interval - what is actual last check date?

Tags: azure, securitycenter

Do you know if (and how) it is possible to check what is a date time of last security check for given security recommendation in Azure Security Center?

I can see only the freshness interval (for some recommendations there is 24h, for other - 30 min), but no idea how to get the "last run" date, to get to know if my security improvement was already "checked" or not yet.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Azure Policy > Compliance, select the initiative, then the policy for which you are interested in knowing the last evaluation date. On the blade for the policy, there should be a column for "Last evaluated", which will show the information you seek.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/how-to/get-compliance-data#portal